# Can I resolve an issue's sub-task using a FishEye smart commit?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-fisheye

### Context

I have a feature request represented as a JIRA issue with the handle **PRJ-11**. My issue has a sub-task with the handle **PRJ-23**. JIRA has the latest FishEye and FishEye Plugin installed and smart commits are enabled.

### Question

If I was to make an SVN commit with the log message:

> PRJ-11 #resolve #time 1w #comment Finished working on the complete feature

FishEye would resolve the parent issue (and presumably the sub-task while it was at it).

If I try to do the same with the sub-task:

> PRJ-23 #resolve #time 1w #comment Finished working on the sub-task

FishEye detects the SVN commit and logs the activity against the sub-task, **but** it does not either advance the workflow of the sub-task or log any time against it or the parent issue.

Have I missed something in my commit message syntax or FishEye configuration?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151412/is-stackoverflow-the-right-place-to-ask-technical-questions-about-jira-configu#comment434142_151412

Comment: FAQ says on-topic questions are those about "software tools commonly used by programmers". This question is on-topic.

Comment: Just FYI @MichaelPryor, you have enough reputation to vote to reopen. :)

Comment: Hmm, maybe this is a bug in FishEye. Check it with http://support.atlassian.com/

Comment: If you find my answer to this question helpful, please accept it.

Comment: @Jordan: Chill out, have patience; I need to get to work and test what you've said. I'm not going to blindly accept the answer! :P

Comment: @Jordan Please do *not* ask people to vote/accept your answers. They will if they wish to.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - It is a pattern that I have seen practiced in other places on SO and by others. I was not aware that it was a verboten practice. Can you please point me at the FAQ that covers this, so that I can refresh my understanding.

Comment: It is done a lot, yes, but it should not be. [See this Meta post for asking for Accepts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140259/152134). [See this one for asking for votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21266/152134)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commit message you present should transition the sub-task to the Resolved state assuming that it is in a state with a Resolve transition available and that you do not require that a sub-task specify a Resolution when being resolved.

If this is not working, I see several possible reasons:

1. The sub-task is in a state without a Resolve transition available to it.
2. The sub-task doesn't have a default Resolution and requires one be specified at resolution
3. The sub-task has one or more required fields not set by a SmartCommit
4. The sub-task requires rights your SmartCommit user doesn't have to resolve it
5. There is a bug in [Fisheye as was suggested|https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/96530/can-i-resolve-an-issue-s-sub-task-using-a-fisheye-smart-commit] at the Atlassian Answers Forum.

A quick comment on something else you said in your question in passing:

> FishEye would resolve the parent issue (and presumably the sub-task while it was at it).

This is not default behavior for JIRA workflows. If you want sub-tasks to be Resolved when the parent is resolved, you would have to customize your workflow.

While having a parent be resolved when all its children are resolved in a behavior I believe is appropriate in some cases, I am not at all sure that resolving sub-tasks when the parent is resolved is at all appropriate.